# My Python code in Visual Studi Code in Mac keeps running the same code

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

So, I am new to Python (programming generally), I did download Python 3.7, Visual Studio Code, Python, code runner extensions inside Visual Studio code and created python file and ran a code say (print ('me')), after that I make a change to the code say, print ('him') , it still runs 'me' not 'him' . I am not sure why. It works only if I open a new file and save it., but I dont wanna do that. I want to make changes on the existing python file not create a new one everytime.

I did follow installing instructions given by this user on Youtube. seems I got the installation right .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saz6A20E9Mk

Comment: After making the change, did you SAVE the file? You need to save the file you are editing.

Comment: By the way, I am using Mac not windows.

Comment: I did save a file. But still shows me the old code

Comment: Then you probably did not save your changes. If you have your "old code", your `(print ('me'))`, change that to `(print ('hello world'))` and navigate to `File -> Save` in Visual Studio Code. From there, try running that file from within VSCode. See what happens.

Comment: YeS! it did work! thank you soo much. but can I automate the save? do I have to do everytime?

Comment: Cool. Let me post as an answer so you and other people on Stack Overflow can reference it. One second.

Comment: in some IDEs/editors you may have option "save before run"

Comment: @Nizl I've included a link that explains how to do what furas was mentioning. Please accept the answer if it satisfies your question :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not actually save your changes. It is important to understand what is happening when you "edit" a file. Your file is "saved" on your computer's hard drive (somewhere). That is what is being run when you press run -- the *saved* file.

If you have your "old code", your `(print ('me'))`, change that to `(print ('hello world'))` and navigate to `File -> Save` in Visual Studio Code. From there, try running that file from within VSCode. See what happens.

When you open it in VisualStudioCode, you are not actually editing that file that is saved on your hard drive! Your computer has placed a temporary copy of it in your computer's memory, which is what is being edited. Therefore, if you want to run your edited code, you need to Save the file you are editing. It is common practice to use keyboard shortcuts, like `Commmand + S` to do that easier.

If you are interested in enabling autosave, to avoid needing to manually save, you can find more details on how to do that at [this visual studio documentation link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics)

Comment: Hi @Nizl, if this fixed your problem, please accept as answer for others